# Define a method, call and interceptor and delegate to target with ByteBuddy?

Tags: java, code-generation, byte-buddy

I have an object `service` that has several methods, one of those methods is `foo(arg1, arg2)`.

Want to create a new wrapper class that:

- has single method `_foo` with *one additional argument*
- delegate `_foo` execution to an interceptor, return is ignored
- finally, delegate call to target `foo` on `service`.

Somehow, I am failing to do so:

```java
final List<Class<?>> parameters =
    Arrays.stream(fooMethod.getParameters())
          .map(Parameter::getType)
          .collect(Collectors.toList());

    parameters.add(AdditionalParameter.class);


final DynamicType.Unloaded unloadedType = new ByteBuddy()
    .subclass(Object.class)
    .implement(interfaceType)
    .name(service.getClass().getSimpleName() + "Dynamic")
    .defineMethod(
        "_" + methodName,
        resolveReturnType(fooMethod),
        Modifier.PUBLIC)
    .withParameters(parameters)
    .intercept(to(fooInterceptor).andThen(
        MethodCall.invoke(fooMethod).on(service)
    ))
    .make();
```

`fooInterceptor` is an `InvocatiomHandler` instance:

```java
public class FooInterceptor implements InvocationHandler {
public Object invoke(
    @This final Object proxy,
    @Origin final Method method.
    @AllArguments final Object[] args) {
    ...
    }
}
```

The exception says that my `fooService` "does not accept 0 arguments".

May I call `service.foo()` from the interceptor - but not using reflection? I am not being able to do so (but didn't play with that part yet).

Help?

EDIT: I have no control in what methods are in `service` so I can't simply use `to(service)` with intercept call; there might be a case where ByteBuddy would not be able to find the matching method.

EDIT2: If I can just 'tell' ByteBuddy the name of target method to bind, that would be awesome. Then I could use `to(service)` with given hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can supply a matcher to `MethodDelegation` to narrow down the methods to consider:

```
MethodDelegation.withDefaultConfiguration().filter(...).to(...)
```

As for your `MethodCall`, you need to specify what arguments to include, `foo` takes two arguments. Since your original arguments seems to be equivalent, you can set:

```
MethodCall.invoke(fooMethod).on(service).withAllArguments();
```

Comment: Filter did the trick :) For the `MethodCall`, it's not all the arguments: all except the last. But again, the filter worked as it seems :)